# Are consecutive products in the form $2^k-1$ divisible by the first such consecutive product?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Is it true that $\frac{(2^m-1)(2^{m-1}-1)\cdots(2^{m-k+1}-1)}{(2^k-1)(2^{k-1}-1)\cdots1}$ is always an integer, for integers $m\ge k\ge1$?

I've noticed that if $x$ divides $y$, then $2^x-1$ divides $2^y-1$, and since both the numerator and denominator have $k$ terms we might be able to prove it like in the proof that binomial coefficients are integers, but I'm not sure how. I've tried induction over $k$ and $m$ but it hasn't led anywhere, so how else can we prove that the answer is yes?

Comment: We're assuming $m\geq k\geq1$, right?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually more is true: for all $m\geq k\geq 1$ the rational function
$$
\frac{(x^m-1)\cdots(x^{m-k+1}-1)}{(x^k-1)\cdots(x-1)}=\frac{(x^m-1)\cdots(x-1)}{(x^k-1)\cdots(x-1)(x^{m-k}-1)\cdots(x-1)}
$$
is a polynomial in $x$. Indeed, let us recall that
$$
x^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)
$$
where $\Phi_d(x)$ are the cyclotomic polynomials, defined by
$$
\Phi_d(x):=\prod_{j\in\{1,...,d\},\ (j,d)=1}(x-\exp(2\pi i d/j)).
$$
It then follows that
$$
(x-1)\cdots(x^K-1)=\prod_{j=1}^K\Phi_j^{\left\lfloor K/j\right\rfloor}.
$$
Hence the original rational function is
$$
\frac{(x^m-1)\cdots(x-1)}{(x^k-1)\cdots(x-1)(x^{m-k}-1)\cdots(x-1)}
=
\frac{\prod_{j=1}^m\Phi_j^{\left\lfloor m/j\right\rfloor}}
{\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\Phi_j^{\left\lfloor k/j\right\rfloor}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{m-k}\Phi_j^{\left\lfloor {m-k}/j\right\rfloor}\right)}
$$
from which it should be possible to conclude (the degree of each cyclotomic polynomial in the denominator is lower than its corresponding degree in the numerator).